# Socket Connection between JAVA Client and Node Server

Tags: java, node.js, sockets

I'm trying do a connection between java client and node server but my client wait a message with `readUTF()` (JAVA) and trying send a message with `socket.write` (Node) how to convert my message to UTF?  or how to send without modified my client?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `readUTF()` unless the sender is using `writeUTF()`.

Use something else: lines; length-word prefix; type-length-value protocol; XML; JSON;